# How to fix this route? Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get quantity in URL but I get an error 'cause I don't know how to properly declare this route. The URL that I'm getting from submited form is this: 
`/2/prideti-i-krepseli/?quantity=45`

And this is how I declared my route:

`{id}/prideti-i-krepseli/?quantity={quantity}`

Comment: Post your full route code and the error you getting

Comment: post how you are trying to get the parameter and the view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your route as

```
{id}/prideti-i-krepseli/
```

and then in that route's controller / function you can get the query string quantity with

`$quantity = $request->input('quantity');`

You should pass a Request argument to that function like this:

```
public function getQuantity(Request $request) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this?

`{id}/prideti-i-krepseli/{quantity}`